# HTTP request timeout when doing concurrent request

Tags: http, go

What will actually happen if I add client timeout when doing an HTTP request?

My code is like this

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/vbauerster/mpb"
    "github.com/vbauerster/mpb/decor"
)

type response struct {
    Header header `json:"header"`
    // Data   data   `json:"data"`
}

type header struct {
    TotalData int `json:"total_data"`
}

type data struct {
    Product []products `json:"products"`
}

type products struct {
    Ads ads `json:"ads"`
}

type ads struct {
    ID string `json:"id"`
}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    empty1 := 0
    empty2 := 0
    empty3 := 0
    loop := 1000
    endpoint := ""
    file, _ := os.OpenFile("file.tmp", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    log.SetOutput(file)
    p := mpb.New(mpb.WithWaitGroup(&wg))
    wg.Add(3)

    bar := p.AddBar(int64(loop),
        // override DefaultBarStyle, which is "[=>-]<+"
        mpb.BarStyle("╢▌▌░╟"),
        mpb.PrependDecorators(
            decor.Name("PB1", decor.WC{W: 3 + 1, C: decor.DidentRight}),
            decor.CountersNoUnit("%d / %d", decor.WCSyncWidth),
        ),
        mpb.AppendDecorators(decor.Percentage(decor.WC{W: 5}),
            decor.OnComplete(
                // ETA decorator with ewma age of 60
                decor.EwmaETA(decor.ET_STYLE_GO, 60), "done",
            ),
        ),
    )
    bar2 := p.AddBar(int64(loop),
        // override DefaultBarStyle, which is "[=>-]<+"
        mpb.BarStyle("╢▌▌░╟"),
        mpb.PrependDecorators(
            decor.Name("PB2", decor.WC{W: 3 + 1, C: decor.DidentRight}),
            decor.CountersNoUnit("%d / %d", decor.WCSyncWidth),
        ),
        mpb.AppendDecorators(decor.Percentage(decor.WC{W: 5}),
            decor.OnComplete(
                // ETA decorator with ewma age of 60
                decor.EwmaETA(decor.ET_STYLE_GO, 60), "done",
            ),
        ),
    )

    bar3 := p.AddBar(int64(loop),
        // override DefaultBarStyle, which is "[=>-]<+"
        mpb.BarStyle("╢▌▌░╟"),
        mpb.PrependDecorators(
            decor.Name("PB3", decor.WC{W: 3 + 1, C: decor.DidentRight}),
            decor.CountersNoUnit("%d / %d", decor.WCSyncWidth),
        ),
        mpb.AppendDecorators(decor.Percentage(decor.WC{W: 5}),
            decor.OnComplete(
                // ETA decorator with ewma age of 60
                decor.EwmaETA(decor.ET_STYLE_GO, 60), "done",
            ),
        ),
    )

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        now := time.Now()
        conChan := make(chan response, loop)

        var wg2 sync.WaitGroup
        wg2.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg2.Done()
            for i := 1; i <= loop; i++ {
                receiver := <-conChan
                if receiver.Header.TotalData == 0 {
                    empty1++
                }
                bar.Increment()
            }
        }()

        for i := 1; i <= loop; i++ {
            if i%50 == 0 {
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            }
            go concurent(conChan, fmt.Sprintf(endpoint, i))
        }

        wg2.Wait()
        log.Println("wg 1", time.Since(now).Seconds())
    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        now := time.Now()
        conChan := make(chan response, loop)

        var wg2 sync.WaitGroup
        wg2.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg2.Done()
            for i := 1; i <= loop; i++ {
                receiver := <-conChan
                if receiver.Header.TotalData == 0 {
                    empty2++
                }
                bar2.Increment()
            }
        }()

        for i := 1; i <= loop; i++ {
            if i%50 == 0 {
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            }
            go concurent(conChan, fmt.Sprintf(endpoint, i))
        }

        wg2.Wait()
        log.Println("wg 2", time.Since(now).Seconds())
    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        now := time.Now()
        conChan := make(chan response, loop)

        var wg2 sync.WaitGroup
        wg2.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg2.Done()
            for i := 1; i <= loop; i++ {
                receiver := <-conChan
                if receiver.Header.TotalData == 0 {
                    empty3++
                }
                bar3.Increment()
            }
        }()

        for i := 1; i <= loop; i++ {
            if i%50 == 0 {
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            }
            go concurent(conChan, fmt.Sprintf(endpoint, i))
        }

        wg2.Wait()
        log.Println("wg 3", time.Since(now).Seconds())
    }()
    p.Wait()

    fmt.Println("empty1:", empty1)
    fmt.Println("empty2:", empty2)
    fmt.Println("empty3:", empty3)
}

func concurent(channel chan response, url string) {

    resp := response{}

    defer func() {
        channel <- resp
    }()

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: 500 * time.Millisecond,
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    res, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err, "1")
        return
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err, "2")
        return

    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(string(body))

        return

    }

}
```

I'm confused because if I don't set the timeout, I will get less empty result with the same time execution when i'm set the timeout, in this case is 500ms. (around 20 second to finish all of the process with or without timeout). In Go docs said

> The Client's Transport typically has internal state (cached TCP
> connections), so Clients should be reused instead of created as needed. Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

What does this mean? Is the client I used for the requests is the same so thats why i'm get more empty result when set the timeout?

Comment: Requests are canceled when the timeout expires. One should expect more failures when specifying a timeout than not.

Comment: It looks like you have 1000 clients making concurrent requests; if you're attempting to make this more efficient, 1000 is likely far too many and you're only making things slower.

Comment: ya but the time execution is the same when im using timeout or without timeout. logically if im not set the timeout, the time execution should be longer if the problem is the request get timeout in 500 ms. and actually this script is only for benchmarking the endpoint with the capability of 1xxx rps, so 1000 is fine because my rps is only like 150 rps by sleeping 1 sec every 50 request / goroutine

Comment: If the average request time is less than the timeout, then you may not see a significant difference in overall time when specifying a timeout.

Comment: hmm i see, thank you for your response guys, i get more insight by try to tracking func concurent execution time and yeah there is like > 500ms time execution

Comment: Do not put tags in the title. We know you're asking about Go because of the tag. Adding the same to the title is just redundant noise.